# Unable to fetch data from firestore database using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch some data randomly from Firestore basically this case is little complex, I looked at the documentation too but am unable to find a solution. So the database contains a collection called userData and this collection store several documents which are the UID's of the users and finally each of these document contains a collection called craft and finally this craft collection contains details like name and other fields.

I tried to get a hold to this data as shown below:

```
Stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData').doc((FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!).uid).collection('craft').snapshots(),
```

and this way I was able to fetch data related to the user Id provided in .doc()

but now I want to display same data on another screen but don't want to fetch data related to a particular user so I am unable to figure out what to put into .doc() to fetch all the random records.

```
Stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData').doc().collection('craft').snapshots(),
```

Complete code of stream builder and listview.builder is given below. Any help will be appreciated :) . I am really frustrated by this problem.

```
  ),
  body: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream:
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData').doc().collection('craft').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              print("No Data");
            };
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                print('none');
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepOrange),
                  ),
                );
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                print('Waiting');
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepOrange),
                    ));
              case ConnectionState.done:
                print('done');
                return Text('');
            };
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot userData = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      Card(
                        elevation: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shadowColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text(userData['displayName']),
                              leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                              trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              subtitle: Text(userData['craft']),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                  Icon(Icons.comment),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                  Icon(Icons.share)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
            );
          },
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
            if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
            return UploadPost();
            }));
            }else{
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
            return LoginScreen();
            }));
            }
          }, backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange, child: Icon(Icons.edit),),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: You have to do multiple queries, first one:
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData')

and then loop through every document and query for each document

Comment: Can you share a piece of sample code please !

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["first_name"]);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This isn't helping me out 

Answer (score 0):

I just did this before but In that case I just had a single collection with auto-id docs.

and I defined my stream like this

```
Stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData').snapshots();
```

and then I displayed the data in the ListView.builder in this way

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot userData = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      Card(
                        elevation: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shadowColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text(userData['post']),
                              leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                              trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              subtitle: Text(userData['name']),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                  Icon(Icons.comment),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                  Icon(Icons.share)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
            );
```

now what's changed is shown in the images below

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbFYF.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgpnD.png)